# Column overflowing into another column-sql server and CSV file

Tags: sql-server, csv

I am bulk inserting a CSV file into SQL server but after examining the result I realised an issue from the CSV file. The contents of the first name column in the CSV file are comma separated and hence are moved into the next column causing a domino effect.(e.g. Let's say the column names are First Name, Number, and Address. The first Name column has a name called James, Bond. Due to the comma, it is moved to the Number comma and hence the supposed data for Number column is also shifted to the address column.
Does anyone have any ideas on how I can rectify this in SQL server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [BULK INSERT / OPENROWSET FormatFile Terminator for CSV file with , (comma) in the data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506484/bulk-insert-openrowset-formatfile-terminator-for-csv-file-with-comma-in-th)

Comment: Thanx Pondlife...that's exactly the issue i'm facing. But how can i get around it to work for my stored procedure since the excel files i'm bulk inserting come from somewhere else and there are so many of them I can't manually check and rectify it in the excel file.

Comment: Do you have a CSV file or an Excel spreadsheet? There's no easy way for any program to split CSV data without a valid column delimiter. Maybe you can write a script if you know what data types are expected in each column e.g. if column 2 is always an integer, then `Bond, James, 2` must be split as `|Bond, James|2` and not as `Bond|James|2`. But if the data for the first two columns is `Bond, James, Blofeld, Ernst` then you have a real problem. If the data is in Excel then it's already structured so you can use SSIS or another tool to get the data.

Comment: yes its a CSV file.and i do know what data types are expected for each column.im currently trying to write a while loop based on the delimiter...

Comment: The best and easiest solution of all is to fix the source data, so I would also find out if whoever or whatever generates the CSV files can do it with a different delimiter.

Comment: yeah.that's what i think too. thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi after opening the raw data in notepad, my colleague and I discovered it had text identifiers and hence I basically just used a format file for the bulk insert. Thanx guys for the suggestions.